# clicking on different links accesses the same page

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have a Job Portal Website, and the website's URL is [http://deutschearbeitsplätzefürromänen.de](http://xn--deutschearbeitspltzefrromnen-mnci35e.de/). When I access the link, the homepage displays correctly. However, when I click on any of the navigation links, regardless of which one I choose, I am redirected back to the homepage. It's important to note that I am new to programming and received this website as a gift. Here is some relevant information:

- The website is primarily written in PHP.
- There is a route file with a function for quick links.
- The folder structure is divided into 'app' for private and 'public_html' for public.
- The programming part is located in the 'app' folder.
- I will also share the function that I believe is relevant to the issue. In 'app/core/functions.php,' there is a function that should bring us to the website's root.

```
function ldir()
{
 /*
  * Gibt das Verzeichnis auf Webspace aus
    * Wird ben�tigt um Links zu generieren
    *
    */

    return "";

}
```

I also share the link that I'm trying to access, which can be found in 'app/view/_header.php'.

```
  <!-- Navigation -->
              <li class="menu-text"><div class="menu-spacer-vertical"></div></li>
              <li class="menu-text show-for-large"><a href="<?= ldir(); ?>/anzeigen">Startseite</a></li>
              <li class="menu-text show-for-large"><a href="<?= ldir(); ?>/tipps">Tipps</a></li>
              <li class="menu-text show-for-large"><a href="<?= ldir(); ?>/warum-cib">Warum Chance im Beruf?</a></li>
              <li class="menu-text show-for-large"><a href="<?= ldir(); ?>/kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
              <li class="menu-text show-for-large"><a href="<?= ldir(); ?>/richtlinien">Richtlinien</a></li>
              <li class="menu-text show-for-large"><a href="<?= ldir(); ?>/impressum">Impressum</a></li>
```

Here, you also have the routes function and the quick links function. That can be found directly in the 'app' folder, specifically in 'app/routes.php'.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['quick-links']['links'])) {
    $_SESSION['quick-links']['links'] = array();
}

if (isset($_SESSION['quick-links']['ttl'])) {
    $_SESSION['quick-links']['ttl'] = intval($_SESSION['quick-links']['ttl']) - 1;
}

if (empty($_SESSION['quick-links']['links']) || intval($_SESSION['quick-links']['ttl']) <= 0) {
    $resQL = mysqli_query($db->con(), "SELECT kennziffer FROM kennziffer");
    $_SESSION['quick-links']['links'] = array();
    while ($rowQL = mysqli_fetch_array($resQL, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($_SESSION['quick-links']['links'], $rowQL['kennziffer']);
    }
    $_SESSION['quick-links']['ttl'] = 72;
}

if (in_array($view, $_SESSION['quick-links']['links'])) {
    header('Location: ' . ldir() . "/anzeige/{$view}");
    exit();
}
// Routes: url=>datei
    $routes = array(
        // Views ohne Parameter
            '' => 'anzeigen',
            'anzeigen' => 'anzeigen',
            'tipps' => 'tipps',
            'warum-cib' => 'warum_cib',
            'kontakt' => 'kontakt',
            'richtlinien' => 'richtlinien',
            'impressum' => 'impressum',
            'nutzungsbedingungen'=>'nutzungsbedingungen',
            'bewerbungsrichtlinien'=>'bewerbungsrichtlinien',
            'datenschutz'=>'datenschutz',
            'hilfe' => 'hilfe',
            'anzeige-aufgeben' => 'anzeige_aufgeben',
            'passwort-aendern' => 'passwort_aendern',
            'passwort-vergessen' => 'passwort_vergessen',
            'passwort-wiederherstellen' => 'passwort_wiederherstellen',
            'sitemap' => 'sitemap',
            'feedback-abmeldung' => 'feedback_abmeldung',
            'meine-bewerbungen' => 'meine_bewerbungen',
            'meine-antworten' => 'meine_antworten',
        // Views mit Parameter
            'anzeige' => 'anzeige',
            'bewerben' => 'bewerben',
            'profil-bearbeiten' => 'profil_bearbeiten',
        // Sonstiges
            'login' => 'login',
        // Admin Views
            'admin' => 'admin/start',
            'dokumentation' => 'admin/dokumentation',
            'zugaenge' => 'admin/zugaenge',
            'suchen' => 'admin/suchen',
            'kennziffern' => 'admin/kennziffern',
            'kriterien' => 'admin/kriterien',
            'projektleiter' => 'admin/projektleiter',
            'firmen' => 'admin/firmen',
            'firmen-premium' => 'admin/firmen_premium',
            'query-builder' => 'admin/query_builder',
            'bewerber' => 'admin/bewerber',
            'stellenanzeigen' => 'admin/stellenanzeigen',
            'kriterien-eintragen' => 'admin/kriterien_eintragen',
            'bewerbungen' => 'admin/bewerbungen',
            'excel' => 'admin/excel',
            'fahrtkosten' => 'fahrtkosten',
            'fahrtkosten-verwalten' => 'admin/fahrtkosten_verwalten',
            'kriterien-definieren' => 'admin/kriterien_definieren',
            'kategorien' => 'admin/kategorien',
            'bewerberantworten' => 'admin/bewerberantworten',
            'tasks' => 'admin/tasks',
            'freigabe-anfordern' => 'admin/freigabe_anfordern',
            'bewerbungen-archiv' => 'admin/bewerbungen_archiv',
            'bewerberinfo' => 'admin/bewerberinfo',
        // Korrespondenzen Views
            'korrespondenzen' => 'korrespondenzen/start',
            'korrespondenzen-vorlagen' => 'korrespondenzen/vorlagen',
            'korrespondenzen-versandprotokolle' => 'korrespondenzen/versandprotokolle',
            'korrespondenzen-versandte-mails' => 'korrespondenzen/versandte_mails'
        );
```

I believe there might be something in the .htaccess file causing this issue, so I'll share the .htaccess file as well.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /index.php/
# If your project is in server root then should be: RewriteBase/
# If project is in folder then it should be: RewriteBase /folder_name/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^.(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Can someone please explain what the problem is?

I attempted to change the function and set the root folder as 'public_html'.

```
function ldir()
{
 /*
  * Gibt das Verzeichnis auf Webspace aus
    * Wird ben�tigt um Links zu generieren
    *
    */

    return "public_html";

}
```

Comment: Hi, i think you can try to change this line in your .htaccess file:
RewriteBase /index.php/ to RewriteBase /

Comment: Hint: it's "Rumänen", not "Romänen"

Comment: Usually the document root is set to `public_html`, so there is no need to include it in URLs.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmenko I tried, but still change nothing.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @brombeer yeah i will change it. Thank you.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmenko can it have a connection with the cron job? What do you think?

Comment: The "document root" is where the web server is configured to serve the files for a domain.  Usually when you find a `public_html` directory, the web server has been configured to show files just from that directory.   For example if the document root is `/home/candea/public_html` then `https://example.com/foo.html` would serve `/home/candea/public_html/foo.html`

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thank you a lot. I change the name of the folder public_html in public and now is working